# Custom Button components in Angular 2 / 4 with analytics

Tags: angular, angular-components

I am making an app with a few forms and service calls. I want to be able to track button clicks in Adobe analytics. I have a utility method .. let's call it "trackClicks()". How do i make a custom button and use it across the app such that if I have a

```
<button (click)="submitForm()">
```

it will also execute trackClicks().

Also, Is it possible to have a directive that will call trackClicks() function or make a custom event that calls it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are better to make a directive for it.

```
@Directive({
    selector: "[adobe-analytics]"
})
export class AdobeAnalytics{

    @HostListener("click", ["$event"])
    public onClick(event: any): void {
        //handle your track clicks things here
    }
}
```

and in your template:

```
<input adobe-analytics type="button" />
```

Comment: hi omeralper .. thank you .. I have a followup question ..  if I do that and add a function to (click) event.. which one will execute first? is there any way to synchronize them?

Answer (score 0):

example from rxjs. hope this helps.

```js
// Code goes here

window.onload = init;

function init() {
  
  const trackbtn = document.querySelector('#trackbtn');  
  const counter = document.querySelector('#counter');
 
  const observable =Rx.Observable.fromEvent(trackbtn, 'click'); 

  const subscriber = observable
    .scan((acc,x) => acc+1,0)
    .subscribe(x => counter.innerHTML = x);
  
    
    
}
```

```html
 <script data-require="rxjs@4.0.6" data-semver="4.0.6" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/4.0.6/rx.all.js"></script>
 <button id = 'trackbtn'>Click me</button>
 <span id = 'counter'>0</span>
```